# Can angular ui router do parallel AND nest view state like this

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have the following workflow:

- The user sees the hotels tab by default.

The url should be: www.domain/#hotels

- Then the user clicks on a hotel-datarow

The url should be www.domain/#hotels/MyName

- Then the user clicks on the Open button

The UI changes and the Reservations tab is the active content

The url should be www.domain/#hotels/MyName/Reservations/20/10/2014 (which is 20/10/2014 in the image)

- The user click the "next day"-button

The url should be www.domain/#hotels/MyName/Reservations/21/10/2014

Can angular ui router display the last url which means the full state including Hotels?

[image]

The sample here from angular ui router just shows nested routing but something for my case which I would name parallel and nested routing:
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

When you ask yourself what is so cool about having the current hote/name in the url then just think of bookmarking it :) something like #hotels/MyName/Reservation/Today

If this would be bookmarked everyday I click on the bookmarked link and in my code I parse for "Today" and translate it to the current date that when I have a quick entry point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is along the lines of what you're after:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AD20fJJMx9eNpuEwOFwj?p=preview

Comment: If you view the iframe plnkr iframe on it's own, you'll see the routes.

Comment: Great! to 90% I just hope it really works too when I have the parallel pages hotels and reservations but we will see :)

Comment: Ill try to come up with a more detailed example a bit later.

Comment: The link to the second Plunk is broken :-(

Comment: @jimbo.io Would you please fix the 2nd link? Thanks!

Comment: @HelloWorld Sorry, the run link tends to expire quickly, but if you go to the first link (in chrome) and do the following you can get to a version that shows the routes:
# Right click on the right panel
# Click on view frame source
# Replace view-source: with http:// in the new window that pops up

Comment: @jimbo.io Interesting feature, thanks also from me: http://run.plnkr.co/BPwiW2JNvaMf9vqO/#/hotels/hotel3/reservations/32-10-2014 that worked!

Comment: @jimbo.io With the new ui router could you still show an angularjs beginner how you/where you would define a controller for the reservation.html. I have still upvoted your answer :)

Comment: ngroute which is angular core routing always inject # in url ? what i need to do if i do not want to show # in url?